# Animating an NSView in from Below

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

How would I animate an NSView in from below. I know there are tutorials like Marcus Zarras which shows how to change from one view to another, but how would I animate in a view which isn't going to replace another view.

Comment: I got some answers to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726795/how-can-i-slide-a-view-in-and-out-of-a-window-in-a-cocoa-program).

Comment: I tried what was in the answer to your question but got stuck on defining the NSRects. Here's what I've tried but has failed. http://grab.by/1vqG

Comment: That's because `NSMakeRect()` returns an `NSRect` struct, not a pointer to an `NSRect` object. you've defined your `NSRect` variables as pointers, but you should be defining them without the asterisks. eg. `NSRect shrunkFirstViewRect = …` etc.

Comment: I see, I got the view to slide in but what's in the other view isn't actually displayed. The view that want to slide in is an NSView in my XIB file connected by an IBOutlet. Why would it not work?

Comment: Here's what I mean. http://drp.ly/9tjco

Answer (score 5):

This tutorial moves a view around, using Core Animation:
[Intro to Core Animation](http://www.macresearch.org/tutorial-intro-core-animation)