# How do I use CATransition to switch view controller in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

I have a Mac application and want to switch between two types of views, from a *detail view* to an *edit view*.

Both have their own view controllers and when the `DetailViewController` is loaded I want to be able to load the `EditViewController` on button push. So far there is no problem.

But I also want to use `CATransition` or similar to have the `EditViewController` slide in from the right while the `DetailViewController` slides out to the left. Just like an image carousel.

How do I modify my current code to support this transition effect? (`QuartzCore` is already imported in the project)

```
- (IBAction)edit:(id)sender {
    // NOTE: self is a DetailViewController
    EditViewController *editController = [[EditViewController alloc] 
            initWithNibName:@"EditView" bundle:nil];
    [editController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:editController.view];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I do something very similar for iPhone. However, the principal should be very similar. In the code samples below change UIView to NSView, and so on.

First, you'll need a root view controller that handles the swap between detail and edit.

In it, have a method something like this. The old and new views passed into the method are the `view`ivars belonging to the old and new view controllers:

```
- (void) slideInNewViewFromRight:(UIView *)newView oldView:(UIView *)oldView remove:(BOOL)remove
{
    UIView *superView = [oldView superview];

    [superView insertSubview:newView belowSubview:oldView];

    CGRect oldFrame = [oldView frame];
    oldFrame.origin = CGPointMake(-kScreenWidth, 0.0f);

    CGRect newFrame = [newView frame];
    newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(kScreenWidth, 0.0f);
    newView.frame = newFrame;

    newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:kSlideOffDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

        if (remove) {
            [self setViewToRemove:oldView];
            [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
        }

        [oldView setFrame:oldFrame];
        [newView setFrame:newFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The`animationDidStop`delegate method will handle removing the old`view`from the`superview` when it completes:

```
- (void) animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    [viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And not forgetting the constants:

```
#define kScreenWidth                    320.0f
#define kSlideInDuration                0.2f
```

Someone is probably out there thinking, why didn't I do this using a`UITabBarController` or`UINavigationController`? The answer is that neither made sense in my case due to the non-hierarchical structure of my view controllers. In fact, mine are more web like. So, I handle everything with a custom root view controller.

As for`CATransition`, I've never used it. I'd be curious to know more about it's applications and if it can provide a more elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: Sadly UIViews have loads more functionality than NSView does. I actually researched your method first since I come from iPhone development to Mac. I don't know why it's more complicated on Cocoa :/

Comment: That's frustrating. Here's a similar question that seems to have a Mac solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726795/how-can-i-slide-a-view-in-and-out-of-a-window-in-a-cocoa-program